# Expandable FAB going through bottom nav bar - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-custom-view, floating-action-button

I made an expandable floating action button like
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiNea.jpg)

i want to make it expand verticly and reveal to more buttons, when its note docked to bottom navigation bar, every thing is ok but when i make it docked it's going through bottom nav bar,

When not expanded looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39DJ6.jpg)
but when expanded like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8DXt.jpg)

How can i make it expand properly
and i also want to align all 3 circle buttons horizontaly.

Thank you so much!

Code:

```
@Composable
fun ExpandableFAB(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onFabItemClicked: (fabItem: ExpandableFABMenuItem) -> Unit,
    menuItems: List<ExpandableFABMenuItem> = ExpandableFABMenuItem.expandableFabMenuItems
) {
    var expandedState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val rotationState by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (expandedState) 45f else 0f
    )

    Column(
        modifier = modifier.wrapContentSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = expandedState,
            enter = fadeIn() + expandVertically(),
            exit = fadeOut()
        ) {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(15.dp)
            ) {
                items(menuItems.size) { index ->
                    ExpandableFABItem(
                        item = menuItems[index],
                        onFabItemClicked = onFabItemClicked
                    )
                }

                item {}
            }
        }

        FloatingActionButton(
            onClick = { expandedState = !expandedState },
            backgroundColor = Blue
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Add,
                contentDescription = "FAB",
                modifier = Modifier.rotate(rotationState),
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ExpandableFABItem(
    item: ExpandableFABMenuItem,
    onFabItemClicked: (item: ExpandableFABMenuItem) -> Unit
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .padding(end = 10.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Text(
            text = item.label,
            fontSize = 12.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(MaterialTheme.colors.surface)
                .padding(horizontal = 6.dp, vertical = 4.dp)
        )

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .size(42.dp)
                .clickable { onFabItemClicked }
                .background(Blue),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = item.icon,
                contentDescription = "Create New Note",
                tint = White
            )
        }
    }
}
```